# The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation (Permission denied)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a Firebase and Flutter project, while adding some security rules for the project and reopening the app show this message.
Security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document=**}{
      allow read,write: if request.auth !=null;
    }
}}
```

The issues start after I successfully login the system, I can see all the data and it works perfectly fine but when I logout then log back in, this is the message displayed on the screen. If I print the currentUser data, I get the correct information on the user but data is not getting displayed.

This is the way my database is set:

[image]

I'm using post data shown in database

Added the code which is denying me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:reddit_tutorial/core/common/error_text.dart';
import 'package:reddit_tutorial/core/common/loader.dart';
import 'package:reddit_tutorial/core/common/post_card.dart';
import 'package:reddit_tutorial/features/auth/controlller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:reddit_tutorial/features/community/controller/community_controller.dart';
import 'package:reddit_tutorial/features/post/controller/post_controller.dart';

late ScrollController controller;

class FeedScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const FeedScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends ConsumerState<FeedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('Feed Screen');
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider)!;
    final isGuest = !user.isAuthenticated;
    // print(isGuest);
    if (!isGuest) {
      return ref.watch(userCommunitiesProvider).when(
            data: (communities) =>
                ref.watch(userPostsProvider(communities)).when(
                      data: (data) {
                        return Scrollbar(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              final post = data[index];
                              return PostCard(post: post);
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      error: (error, stackTrace) {
                        return ErrorText(
                          error: error.toString(),
                        );
                      },
                      loading: () => const Loader(),
                    ),
            error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(
              error: error.toString(),
            ),
            loading: () => const Loader(),
          );
    }
    return ref.watch(userCommunitiesProvider).when(
          data: (communities) => ref.watch(guestPostsProvider).when(
                data: (data) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final post = data[index];
                      return PostCard(post: post);
                    },
                  );
                },
                error: (error, stackTrace) {
                  return ErrorText(
                    error: error.toString(),
                  );
                },
                loading: () => const Loader(),
              ),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(
            error: error.toString(),
          ),
          loading: () => const Loader(),
        );
  }
}
```

```
final userCommunitiesProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  final communityController = ref.watch(communityControllerProvider.notifier);
  return communityController.getUserCommunities();
});
```

```
  Stream<List<Community>> getUserCommunities(String uid) {
    return _communities
        .where('members', arrayContains: uid)
        .orderBy('name', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<Community> communities = [];
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        communities.add(Community.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
      }
      return communities;
    });
  }
```

```
final userPostsProvider =
    StreamProvider.family((ref, List<Community> communities) {
  final postController = ref.watch(postControllerProvider.notifier);
  return postController.fetchUserPosts(communities);
});
```

```
Stream<List<Post>> fetchUserPosts(List<Community> communities) {
    return _posts
        .where('communityName',
            whereIn: communities.map((e) => e.name).toList())
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (event) => event.docs
              .map(
                (e) => Post.fromMap(
                  e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        );
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also add the code that you're using and gets rejected.

Comment: I did the edits suggested by you @AlexMamo

Comment: Please also add the code that you're using and gets rejected.

Comment: @AlexMamo i did the edits

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you're performing a query inside the "users" collection?

Comment: Actually I solved my problem by refreshing all the riverpod providers after signing in, so now this problem does not come into picture